# Diagrams in a model category

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, localization, model-categories

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a model category with class of weak equivalences $W$ and $\mathcal{J}$ a small category. The category of diagrams $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{M})$ inherits a class of weak equivalences $W_{\mathcal{J}}$, those natural transformations which are objectwise weak equivalences. If $\mathcal{M}$ fails to be left or right proper then $(\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{M}), W_{\mathcal{J}})$ may fail to be a model category. Is it still the case that $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{M})[W_\mathcal{J}^{-1}]$ is locally small? I suspect not but would appreciate a counterexample.

Comment: It’s really a pretty rare problem since regardless of properness if $M$ is Quillen equivalent to something combinatorial then the functor category gets the injective and projective model structures. Is this really coming up for you or more of a curiosity?

Comment: I also guess that if local smallness were to fail it would imply that the functor category isn’t a presentation of the $\infty$-categorical functor category, so that it’s homotopically wrong. Sounds like a risk of a wild goose chase to me.

Comment: Definitely more of a curiosity. I was writing up some notes about derivators and was wondering the homotopy-derivator of a model category is valued in locally small categories without further assumptions. But I didn't have a particular category in mind